# Google Analytics and Apache2 log not agreeing

Tags: apache, apache2, google-analytics

I am using an advertising platform that claims they are sending clicks to my site. I am using a URL appended with `?someString` to clearly identify page requests that are the result of a click on the ad. My Google Analytics reports shows that this URL has gotten page requests approximately the same number of times the advertising platform claims they sent clicks to me. However, my apache2 log shows no evidence of these page requests.

To be clear, I can create a request to `http://mywebsite.com/landingpage/?someString` and that shows up in my log. However, these clicks that the ad network claims do not show up. If the situation was only that, I would assume it was either click breakage or outright lies from the ad network. However, these clicks from the ad network are showing up in Google Analytics too.

Any thoughts on how this could be happening? Could the Google Analytics script be called without a page request being logged in my apache2 logs?

Comment: Any chance you're looking in a log file for the wrong day -- Aren't Apache logs in UTC?

Comment: No chance. I rotate them by the week. Furthermore, my search method is to grep the whole directory of files for the `someString` clause I add to the click URL.

Comment: If you visit `?someOtherString`, does it show up in your logs and GA? Are you using any kind of content delivery network that might be serving the page up from a cache? That's all I can think of...

Comment: yes, if I visit it, i see the activity in my logs. In fact, if I click on the ad myself (I found it in the wild), I see the activity in my logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for the sake of documenting the solution in case anybody ever comes across a similar scenario. As usual, this was a "doh!" moment when I realized what was going on:

Turns out the partition on which my apache2 logs was full. As a result, the log file didn't contain everything. Once I freed up some space (by deleting old log files), everything worked as expected. That is, my Google Analytics and web server log files agreed.